# Oracle grant execute to package doesn't work

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-grant

I created package in schema CUST_DEV. In proc from my package I use proc from other package CUST_DS.CUST_CTL.proc(). 
 When i recompile my package i received error: PLS-00201: CUST_DS.CUST_CTL.proc must be declared. 
I have  given privileges

```
grant execute on CUST_DS.CUST_CTL to CUST_DEV with grant option
```

I check in db_tab_priv new privileges for CUST_DEV on CUST_DS.CUST_CTRL. 
But when i recompile my package i receive the same error. What i do wrong?

I have  given privileges with grant option and without

Comment: Does the CUST_CTL package actually have the procedure "proc" defined in its header? Not just its body, its header. Do you see the procedure in `all_procedures.procedure_name` where `object_name = 'CUST_CTL' and owner = 'CUST_DS'`?

Comment: @Paul W, I created session to db with user = 'CUST_DEV', then exec query `select * from all_procedures where procudure_name = 'PROC' and owner = 'CUST_DS'`. It returns  1 row: owner CUST_DS, procedure_name = 'PROC', AUTHID = 'DEFINER'. In package CUST_CTL i checked declaration of porcedure 'PROC' in header of package.  It is there.

Comment: Can you please paste the actual code (or snippet) of (1) the calling proc, and (2) the package header showing the procedure header definition?

Comment: Header definision:   
`create or replace package CUST_DS.CUST_CTL is   
procedure proc(in_batch_id in number);    
end CUST_CTL; ` 
calling proc: 
`create or replace package body CUST_DEV.MY_PACK is  
procedure proc(in_Date in varchar2) is  
begin  
CUST_CTL.proc(5);  
end;  
end MY_PACK; `

Comment: @Paul W thank you, i find error. I need to add schema name in calling proc: `CUST_DS.CUST_CTL.proc(5) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add schema name in calling proc: `CUST_DS.CUST_CTL.proc(5)`  . Thank you, @PaulW